# Object declared outside of Promise.prototype.then() returns undefined when used inside of it

Tags: javascript

In the following function, I'm having an issue where `options` is considered undefined inside of .then(), even though the `console.log(options.destination)` prior to the `storageObj` function call chain prints correctly.

```
/**
 * Returns a promise that resolves an object including the
 * file destination if the requested file is downloaded successfully
 * and rejects if there is an error whle downloading the file.
 *
 * @param {Object} storageObj GCS Storage object instance.
 * @param {String} bucketName Name of the bucket to access in the GCS Storage object.
 * @param {String} filePath Path of the file to access in the given bucketName.
 * @param {String} destinationDir Name of the direcory to download the file to.
 * @returns Promise
 */
function downloadGCSFileToDir(storageObj, bucketName, filePath, destinationDir) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("filePath is: " + filePath);
        const filePathParts = filePath.split("/");
        const destination = `${destinationDir}/${filePathParts[filePathParts.length - 1]}`;
        const options = { "destination": destination };
        console.log(options.destination);
        storageObj
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .file(filePath)
            .download(options)
            .then(() => {
                console.log(`gs://${bucketName}/${filePath} downloaded to ${options.destination}`);
                resolve({ "destination": options.destination });
            })
            .catch(err => reject(new Error(`downloadGCSFileToDir failed: ${err}`)));
    });
}
```

But if I use `destination` inside of .then() as such:

```
function downloadGCSFileToDir(storageObj, bucketName, filePath, destinationDir) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("filePath is: " + filePath);
        const filePathParts = filePath.split("/");
        const destination = `${destinationDir}/${filePathParts[filePathParts.length - 1]}`;
        const options = { "destination": destination };
        console.log(options.destination);
        storageObj
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .file(filePath)
            .download(options)
            .then(() => {
                console.log(`gs://${bucketName}/${filePath} downloaded to ${destination}`);
                resolve({ "destination": destination });
            })
            .catch(err => reject(new Error(`downloadGCSFileToDir failed: ${err}`)));
    });
}
```

it prints as expected. Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: What is that `download` method? Any chance it destroys the `options` object passed to it?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? You say that "*`options` is considered undefined*", did you mean that `options.destination` is considered undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options` isn't undefined inside your `then`; `options.destination` is. The reason is that the `download` method [deletes the `destination` property](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/98862e179ba5420c70a174759cadde9cc47fdc41/src/file.js#L1137-L1138) from the `options` object.

```
File.prototype.download = function(options, callback) {
  if (is.fn(options)) {
    callback = options;
    options = {};
  }

  callback = once(callback);

  var destination = options.destination;
  delete options.destination;  // <--- here

  // ...
```

As to why it does that, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: What a horrible library.

Comment: Was so excited to see this, then changed `options` to `opts` in my code. Still reproducing the issue. Hmmm....

Comment: In JavaScript objects are passed by reference. Changing the name of the variable will have no effect. Whatever object you pass as the first argument to `download` will be the object that gets modified inside `download`. If you don't want the object to be modified, you'll need to pass a copy, e.g. `.download(Object.assign({}, options))`.

Comment: Worked. Thank you! I had a feeling it was some kind of referencing issue.